# Fixed-point convesion: 31...24 exponent with 23...0 fractional to Q25 value?

Tags: c, signal-processing, fixed-point

I need to calculate fixed-point value for the formulae:

`e ^ ( Konst/x*y )`

I use a 3rd party `divide()` and `antilog()` functions, something like:

```
div = divide( Konst, x*y );
out = antilog( div );
```

My `divide()` gives at output
`bits 23…0 fractional part` (this is in fact `Q0.31` format when shifted `<< 8`)
 and
`bits 31…24 exponent`.

The `antilog()` expects at input `Q6.25` value.

How can I feed something meaningfull to `antilog()` in `Q6.25` format?
How do I go from one format to another in this specific case?

p.s.
What happens if `divide` gives a very big output that cannot fit into `Q6.25` without scaling? In that case, how to do `e^(scale*Q6.25)`?

Comment: What is Q6.25? No google results.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: A 32 bits fixed-point value with range (-64.0, +64.0).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format).

Answer (score 0):

"bits 23…0 fractional part (this is in fact Q0.31 format when shifted << 8"
Well, the point is that you don't shift by 8, but by the exponent part (bits 31..24). Note that the exponent is almost certainly biased; bits 00000000 are NOT exponent `<<0` but probably `>>127` or so. (Check documentation).

SO, subtract the bias, subtract another 6 for Q6.25, and shift.

Comment: Not biased. `This routine performs division of vectors written in Q31 format. It returns the fractional and exponential portion of the division result. Since the division may generate result greater than 1, it returns
fractional portion frac in Q(31-exp) format and exponent exp so true division result in the Q0.31 may be found by shifting fractional part left by exponent value.`

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the "subtract another 6 for Q6.25, and shift"? What gets subtracted, what gets shifted? Example would help...

Comment: @Danijel: You'd better read up on fixed-point and floating-point formats. Consider how you represent the value `2.0` in your FP format, in Q6.25 and Q4.27. The FP exponent means a multiplication by `2^exp`. And multiplication by a power of 2 is a bitshift. Hence, `*2^exp` is equivalent to `<<exp`. If we ignore bits falling off on either side, `<<a >>b` is `<<a-b` provided `a>b`, or else `>>b-a`